# No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=73 uv=1 libc=glibc

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-gyp

I recently started using fuse-box beta 4.0.0 in my Electron project, I bundled everything using fusebox and I get...

```
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=73 uv=1 libc=glibc
    at Function.load.path (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:118703:9)
    at load (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:118683:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:37119:43)
    at $import (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:428:11)
    at locals.require (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:411:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:37015:17)
    at $import (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:428:11)
    at locals.require (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:411:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:3557:21)
    at $import (C:\Users\ender\Desktop\Dot Browser\dot-desktop\dist\main\6b4091b_app.js:428:11)
```

I've reported to the Electron authors, and been told that this isn't anything to do with Electron and it is in fact to do with `glibc`. However the `glibc` library has been archived, and I have nowhere to report this apart from here.

I've tried using an older version of Electron, no luck.

```
load.path = function (dir) {
  dir = path.resolve(dir || ".");
  try {
    var name = runtimeRequire(path.join(dir, "package.json")).name.toUpperCase().replace(/-/g, "_");
    if (process.env[name + "_PREBUILD"]) dir = process.env[name + "_PREBUILD"];
  } catch (err) {}
  if (!prebuildsOnly) {
    var release = getFirst(path.join(dir, "build/Release"), matchBuild);
    if (release) return release;
    var debug = getFirst(path.join(dir, "build/Debug"), matchBuild);
    if (debug) return debug;
  }
  var prebuilds = path.join(dir, "prebuilds", platform + "-" + arch);
  var parsed = readdirSync(prebuilds).map(parseTags);
  var candidates = parsed.filter(matchTags(runtime, abi));
  var winner = candidates.sort(compareTags(runtime))[0];
  if (winner) return path.join(prebuilds, winner.file);
  var target = ["platform=" + platform, "arch=" + arch, "runtime=" + runtime, "abi=" + abi, "uv=" + uv, armv ? "armv=" + armv : "", "libc=" + libc].filter(Boolean).join(" ");
  throw new Error("No native build was found for " + target);
};
function readdirSync(dir) {
  try {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir);
  } catch (err) {
     return []; // This line is 118703:9 as mentioned in the error.
  }
}
```

Bear in mind, this is bundled by fuse-box.

The app should launch, however it's being stopped by this.

Comment: you say this is when you started using fuse-box 4 beta? If so, have you contacted _them_ to report that their beta is causing problems? The Electron project would indeed be the wrong place to start.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've already reported this to the fuse box dev, and he told me it's not FuseBox's fault.

Comment: I have this problem as well. Did you ever get it to work @EnderDev?

Comment: I moved my code over to webpack, and when the same error appeared again, it mentioned `leveldown` so I just uninstalled it and it was working fine after that.